# How to delete multiple documents with firebase functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to delete old notifications periodically via Firebase functions.
My db structure looks like this in cloud Firestore:

```
notification/autoID1/messages/autoID2/duration:Date1
                             /autoID3/duration:Date2

             autoID4/messages/autoID5/duration:Date3
                             /autoID6/duration:Date4
```

I have tried many approaches, but none of them worked. Here is an example:

```
exports.deleteoldnotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: { status: (arg0: number) => { send: () => void; }; }) => {
    const timeNow = new Date();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const datatodelete:any= {};
    db.collection('notification').get().then((snap: { forEach: (arg0: (collection: any) => void) => void; }) => {
        snap.forEach((collection: any) => {
            db.collection('notification').doc(collection.id).collection('messages').get().then((snapshot: { forEach: (arg0: (doccollection: any) => void) => void; }) => {
                snapshot.forEach((doccollection) => {
                    const durations = new Date(doccollection.data().duration).getTime();
                    if (durations > timeNow) {
                        datatodelete[doccollection.id]= '/notification/'+collection.id+'/messages/'+doccollection.id;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        if(Object.keys(datatodelete).length>0)
        return db.doc(datatodelete).delete();
        else
        return res.status(200);
    });
});
```

This finished with timeout.

So, my question is:

How to delete multiple documents at the same time, and what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Same question as earlier: what is `(snap: { forEach: (arg0: (collection: any) => void) => void; })` meant to do?

Comment: I don't know, that jumped out as an error,that the type is missing,and corrected it automatically.It says: "Parameter 'snap' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: Ah, so it's the type of the `snapshot` parameter. That would actually be a `QuerySnapshot`, but "an object with `forEach`" might be enough for this use-case.

Comment: I think the problem is around the date comparison,or with the delete command,but I don't know since I'm very knew to this.